# Make GridView horizontally scrollable using code

Tags: java, android

I created a `GridView` using code rather than xml as follows.

```
GridView seatPlan = new GridView(SeatSelectionActivity.this);
seatPlan.setId(999999);
seatPlan.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
seatPlan.setColumnWidth(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
seatPlan.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM);
seatPlan.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

I can make the `GridView` horizontally scrollable by setting the `scrollbars` property as follows.

```
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
```

I would like to be able to set the property using code.

Comment: visit https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

Comment: There were no related methods specified in the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars
Its better to use customViews.